# How to order my query by most duplicates in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

On my website, users can post images.

Images can have tags.

There's 4 tables for this, the `images` table, the `images_tag` pivot table, the `tag` table, and of course the `users` table.

A user can have multiple images with the same tag(s).

I can pull up the tags a user has used across all his images with this query:

```
$userTags = Tag::whereHas('images', function($q) use($user) {
    $q->where('created_by', $user->id);
})->get();
```

However, I want to make it so that I can order these tags based on how frequently a user uses them. In other words, I want to order by duplicates. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you're going to need to `join` the `images_tags` and `images` tables, count the number of tags, and order by those tags.

```
$tags = Tag::selectRaw('tags.*, COUNT(images.id) AS total')
    ->join('images_tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'images_tags.tag_id')
    ->join('images', 'images.id', '=', 'images_tags.image_id')
    ->where('images.created_by', $user->id)
    ->groupBy('tags.id')
    ->orderBy('total', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

The above query will only work in MySQL if the `only_full_group_by` option is disabled. Otherwise, you're going to need to either rewrite this to use a sub query, or do the ordering in the returned Laravel `Collection`. For example:

```
$tags = Tag::selectRaw('tags.*, COUNT(images.id) AS total')
    ->join('images_tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'images_tags.tag_id')
    ->join('images', 'images.id', '=', 'images_tags.image_id')
    ->where('images.created_by', $user->id)
    ->groupBy('tags.id')
    ->get();

$tags = $tags->sortByDesc(function ($tag) {
    return $tag->total; 
});
```

If you want to add this to your user model, per your comment, create a function similar to the following:

```
public function getMostUsedTags($limit = 3)
{
    return Tag::selectRaw('tags.*, COUNT(images.id) AS total')
        ->join('images_tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'images_tags.tag_id')
        ->join('images', 'images.id', '=', 'images_tags.image_id')
        ->where('images.created_by', $this->id)
        ->groupBy('tags.id')
        ->orderBy('total', 'desc')
        ->limit($limit)
        ->get();   
}
```

Comment: When trying the bottom example, it returns "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sortByDesc()"

Comment: Ehh.... I made an edit to the post to respond to you, but it ended up making a completely different post. What the hell?

Comment: The error messages are pretty explicit, and are stating that the table names are incorrect. Update the table names to match the names you're using.

Comment: I forgot I don't use standard pivot table names. Your response was good. Thanks!

Comment: Also, would it be possible to add such a query to my user model? A function that would, say, show the top 3 most used tags by that user, for example?

Comment: Yes. Modify the above query and limit the results. Which of the above options did you use?

Comment: Updated with an an example.